# Angular Pipe not working as expected

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

Hi I am trying to build a custom pipe for my *ngFor, I want to check if a substring exists, if it does, print it, otherwise not.
Here my code, thanks in advance:

**EDIT** thank you for the reply, this is my solution now:

```
    let secondDelimiterVal = this.getPosition(value.location,".",2);
    let secondDelimiterField = this.getPosition(field,".",2);
    let v = value.location.toLowerCase().substr(value.location.indexOf(".")+1,secondDelimiterVal-value.location.indexOf(".")-1);
    let needle = field.toLocaleLowerCase().substr(field.indexOf(".")+1,secondDelimiterField-field.indexOf(".")-1);      
    return v.includes(needle) == true;
```

My Pipe:

```
import { Vulnerability } from '@models/api/vulnerability.model';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'fullTextSearch',
  pure: false
})

export class FullTextSearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: Vulnerability[],field: string, include: boolean): any {
    if(include){

      return values.filter(value => {
        value.location.toLowerCase().substr(value.location.indexOf("."),value.location.lastIndexOf(".")).
        includes(field.toLocaleLowerCase().substr(field.indexOf("."),field.lastIndexOf("."))) === true;
      });
    } 
    else{
      return values.filter(value => value.location.toLowerCase().substr(value.location.indexOf("."),value.location.lastIndexOf(".")).search(field.toLocaleLowerCase().substr(field.indexOf("."),field.lastIndexOf("."))) == -1);
    } 
  }
}
```

How I call the pipe:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let finding of (verifiedFindings| fullTextSearch:job.packageName:true);index as i" > 
      <td>{{finding?.id}}</td>
      <td>{{finding?.title}}</td>
      <td>{{finding?.comment || finding?.location}}</td>
    </tr>    
...
        <tr *ngFor="let finding of newVerifiedElements | fullTextSearch:'job.packageName':false;index as i" class="table-info" > 
            <td>{{finding?.id}}</td>
            <td>{{finding?.title}}</td>
            <td>{{finding?.comment || finding?.location}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: The callback passed to filter() doesn't return anything: **return** value.location.toLow... Also, comparing a boolean with true is useless. Just return the boolean.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yesterday I had a long day and got frustrated :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint, this got me going:

```
  return values.filter(value => {
    let secondDelimiterVal = this.getPosition(value.location,".",2);
    let secondDelimiterField = this.getPosition(field,".",2);
    let v = value.location.toLowerCase().substr(value.location.indexOf(".")+1,secondDelimiterVal-value.location.indexOf(".")-1);
    let needle = field.toLocaleLowerCase().substr(field.indexOf(".")+1,secondDelimiterField-field.indexOf(".")-1);      
    return v.includes(needle) == true;
    });
```